# Windows Phone 8 & Internet Explorer 10 caches 302 redirects

Tags: jquery-mobile, caching, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, http-status-code-302

We are developing a web app for mobile devices and we are experiencing a rare caching issue in Windows Phone 8 & Internet Explorer 10.

Our app is based on JSF and jQueryMobile. And we are using de "redirect-after-post" system for navigation.

When we make a call to a new page two requests should be executed and so they are in all the  OS an navigators except in our beloved Microsoft system (WP8 & IE10, Nokia Lumia 620):

1. Navigator requests URL
2. Server returns HTTP 302 status with new location
3. Navigator requests new location

The fact is that WP8 & IE10 doesn`t execute the last request, and shows a cached result. We are including the "Cache-control", "Pragma" and "Expires" headers in the 302 response to make the navigator not to show a cached page, but IE10 ignores them.

Any clue to solve this problem?

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forcing the Uri returned in step 2 to be unique (append a random or incrementing value to the end of the query string).
This works around the caching behaviour in the HttpWebRequest class in the SDK.

Comment: Making the 302 redirect URI unique works fine, but we have gone deeper in avoiding navigator caching.

Comment: We don't know why, but making a servlet filter that includes de "no cache" headers in every(we have used a mapping that fits our needs) response solved the problem. We were already including the headers in all the redirects, but it seems that was not enough for WP8 & IE10...